# How do CI environments protect their secrets from being logged?

Tags: continuous-integration

I was interested in retrieving the DB URI I was using in a personal project (Node app), so I went to try and `console.log` the environment variable that was storing it and pushed my change, and GitHub Actions showed `***` on the specific `console.log` statement when it ran my tests. Moreover, I found this interesting how they're able to do this, so I tried spinning up a Mongoose connection to my server and then logging the internals of the connection object. Low and behold, the port, base address, etc. were censored as well (and only those sensitive fields), even despite the URI being broken up into pieces. Like if I had `localhost:27017` as my URI, I saw that the line `{port: 27017}` was censored as well when I logged out Mongoose internals, which seems much more complicated than filtering on the environment variables.

This seems like it would be something extremely complex to implement well and I'm wondering how it's done. I thought at first maybe there was a regex that would match the environnment variable value, but then I realized that if there was an environment variable set to, say, `true`, then it's not going to censor all the lines logged that contain the keyword `true`.

Comment: I don't know how _Github Actions_ do it specifically, but Jenkins searches in the output text for all known secrets and replaces them.

Comment: @tkausl that makes sense—this just seems much more advanced given that it's able to censor out partitions of the secret strings (I added some more clarification to display what I mean)